# Two questions about the Hom functors

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra, functors

Given a locally small category $\mathcal{C}$, Wikipedia [defines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hom_functor#Formal_definition) the Hom functors as

[image]

At my lectures (for the more specific case of $\mathcal{C}=\operatorname{R-Mod}$  -- the category of R-modules for some ring R) the functor $Hom_R(-, M)$ was defined as a functor between $\operatorname{R-Mod}^{op}\rightarrow \operatorname{AbGrp}$.

1. I think I understand why the codomain is $\operatorname{AbGrp}$, but I don't understand why the domain is the opposite category $\operatorname{R-Mod}^{op}$? How is it possible that Wikipedia gives the domain to be $\mathcal{C}$?
2. Also, my notes claim that it follows from the left-exactness of the Hom-functor $Hom_\mathcal{A}(M, -): \mathcal{A} \rightarrow \operatorname{AbGrp}$ (here $\mathcal{A}$ is an arbitrary Abelian category) that $Hom_R(-, M): \operatorname{R-Mod}^{op} \rightarrow \operatorname{AbGrp}$ is also left exact. Could you explain why this is a corollary of the left-exactness of $Hom_\mathcal{A}(M,-): \mathcal{A}\rightarrow\operatorname{AbGrp}$?

Comment: A contravariant functor $F:A\to B$ is a functor $A^{\operatorname{op}}\to B$. This means it "reverses arrows".

Comment: The key to 1. is contravariance. Wikipedia (apparently) is perfectly happy to allow covariant and contravariant functors, but some authors insist on writing contravariant functors as covariant functors from the opposite category.

Comment: @RyleeLyman so would it be accurate to say that my confusion regarding the first question is just a confusion regarding syntax? Ie that the insistence on the opposite category as domain is just due to the fact that if we didnt then the functor wouldnt commute with composition as expected?

Comment: yes, that's right.

Comment: @RyleeLyman In my experience I would say essentially all authors use the convention you describe.

Comment: @KevinCarlson I agree from my (limited) reading in category theory. Hatcher in *Algebraic Topology,* though, is happy to just define a "contravariant functor" when discussing cohomology, since he prefers to minimize the categorical perspective in the main text.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's probably worth explicitly saying that the Wikipedia definition is the usual $\mathbf{Set}$-[enriched](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/enriched+category) (or unenriched) definition while the hom you refer to is $\mathbf{Ab}$-enriched. While many facts are true of enriched hom functors regardless of what they're enriched over (given some basic structure), not everything translates. Further, similar notation is often used for the [internal hom](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/internal+hom).